# Action failed: c:CL_1303_Eg1_AccountDataTile$controller$getme [Key is not defined]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Class

```
public class CL_1303_Eg1_AccountTable {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> acl(String kw)
    {
        String Qr='Select Id,Name,Phone,Fax from Account where name like \'%' + kw + '%\'';
        List<account> AAA=Database.query(Qr);
        Return AAA;
    }

}
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="CL_1303_Eg1_AccountTable" >
    <aura:attribute name="accnt" type="Account[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Keyword" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="col" type="List"/>
    
    <lightning:card title="Account Search">
        <lightning:input value="{!v.Keyword}"/>
        <lightning:button label="Get Account Data" onclick="{!c.getme}"/>
    </lightning:card>
    
    <lightning:layout >
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.accnt}" var="a">
            <lightning:layoutitem size="3" padding="aroud-small">
                <lightning:card iconName="standard:account">
                    <aura:set attribute="title">
                        {!a.Name}
                    </aura:set>
                    Phone:{!a.Phone} <P></P>
                    Fax:{!a.Fax}     <p></p>
                    Industry:{!a.Industry} <p></p>
                </lightning:card>
            </lightning:layoutitem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
    
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    getme : function(component, event, helper) {
        var key=component.get("v.Keyword");
        var MM=component.get("c.acl");
        MM.setParams({"kw":Key});
        MM.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state=='SUCCESS')
            {
                var result=response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.accnt",result);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(MM);
    }
})
```

Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:CL_1303_Eg1_AccountDataTile/>    
</aura:application>
```

Comment: It should be `key` in small case i.e. `MM.setParams({"kw":key});`, Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: You've changed your question in a way that invalidates my answer. Please stick to one question per post.

Comment: @DavidReed Sorry David. I will stick to one question per Post. Tq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component doesn't declare a controller. You must use the `controller` attribute on your Aura component to declare a server-side controller.

---

Your other problem is that JavaScript is case-sensitive and you have mixed `Key` and `key`, which are different JS identifiers.